# Firmware "Flash progress" stuck at 0%

Tags: dell, flash, firmware

```
Environment details: 
Personal Computer: Dell OptiPlex-5090
Operating System: Ubuntu 20.04
```

On my computer I got `OptiPlex firmware` update in official `Ubuntu Software` app, after updating it, I received a notification to restart my computer.

After restarting computer, I see Dell-logo and Flash progress, the firmware update progress remained at 0% for a long time.

If I power-off computer by long pressing power button and turns on computer, computer starts without firmware update, and I see update for firmware again in my `Ubuntu Software` app

Answer (score 0):

I had two external adapters connected to my pc: `Wifi adapter` and `Bluetooth adapter`

After removing them, `Flash progress` started moving above 0% and fireware update completed successfully.